# While vs For loop counter

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Just starting out with learning Python, but I can't come up with the logic behind this and I was hoping someone could clarify.

```
# this works without a counter
Numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for Numbers in Numbers:
     print(Numbers)
```

But

```
# this doesn't work without a counter
Numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
while Numbers in Numbers <= 5:
     print(Numbers)
```

So 'for loop' can progress through each value and report it, but 'while-loop' can't?
Why does 'while loop' require a counter variable to progress when for doesn't?
Am I understanding this correctly, and if so, is there any practical reason for the discontinuity?

EDIT: I appreciate the comments about how the loops work but that's not really my question. After thinking about it, I think I came up with a better way to ask my question, and again, I apologize if this all comes off as hopelessly ignorant, but I only started learning coding/python 3 days ago. So previously I was coming at it from the direction of why while-loops don't have similar functionality to for-loops, so here's the same question from the opposite direction... Why do for-loops exist if they are just a simplified while-loop?

```
#convince me this isn't a for loop, and if it is, why do for loops exist?
Numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
x = 0
while x < len(Numbers):
     print(Numbers[x])
     x = x + 1
```

Comment: Do you mean `for Number in Numbers`, then `print(Number)`?

Comment: `Numbers in Numbers <= 5` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: The only thing in common with for loops and while loops is they iterate over something, while loops need a condition to evaluate

Answer (score 1):

`for loop` is basically process each element one by one and `while loop` is little bit different, it process the data until your condition is true. Here we used counter as condition so when `while loop` condition going to fail loop can stop working. So basically if you want to process each data one by one you can go for `for loop` and if you want to process data up to some certain condition you can go for `while loop`. ex. if you have 5 element and you have to process all then you can go for `for loop` and if you want to process data multiple time or in dynamic sequence you can use `while loop`.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify my confusion a little... for-loop seems to proceed exactly like a x=0, x=x+1 to the end of the list. If for-loop does it without needing a counter, why wouldn't while-loop do that until it met a value that satisfied the condition?

Comment: because for loop iterate  each element so it doesn't required any stoping condition, if last  element  of your sequence processed then for loop getting stop but while loop required condition for stop. if your condition never failed then while loop is going to infinite state.

Answer (score 1):

A [while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop will loop until the condition is False and a [for](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop will loop until you have looped through all elements in the list. Some exemples how you can use them:

A for loop that prints the numbers 0 to 9. `Number` will reference the element in the list `Numbers`

```
Numbers = range(10) #same result as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for Number in Numbers:
     print(Number)
```

A while loop that prints the numbers 0 to 5. `i` will reference the position in the list.

```
Numbers = range(10) #same result as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
i = 0
while Numbers[i] <= 5:
     print(Numbers[i])
     i += 1
```

One more example added, see comment below:

```
test = True
while test==True:
    number = input("Enter an int: (enter 0 to exit)\n")
    if number.isdigit(): # Checks if an int has been enterd
        number = int(number)
        if number == 0: # Exit the while loop if you enter 0 
            test = False
        else:
            for i in range(number):
                print(i)
```

Comment: Sorry, not to be rude but I know WHAT they do, at least generally. What I don't understand is why a for loop iterates without a counter and while doesn't. It seems that for the sake of consistency, a for loop should require a counter to iterate, or a while loop lacking a counter should iterate from the start until the condition is met. What I am questioning is the logic behind the discontinuity.

Comment: A `for` loop is used when you want to loop through all elements in a list. And a `while` loop is used when you don't have a list. Like if you want to take user input until they have entered the correct input or if you want to do something until a variable is false. I have added an example above that uses a `for` and a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> So 'for loop' can progress through each value and report it, but 'while-loop' can't? Why does 'while loop' require a counter variable to progress when for doesn't?

I think the disconnect here is that a `while` loop is often used in cases when a `for` loop cannot. Here's a simple example:

```
answer = input("Do you want to continue?")
while answer == yes:
    print("we are doing stuff..."
    answer = input("Do you want to continue?")
```

In a case like this, a counter is meaningless because we have no idea how many times the loop will repeat. We might be able to create an equivalent `for` loop, but it would be unnecessarily complicated.